# What does the D stand for in the steel grade 16MND5

Tags: steel, standards

I would like to know what does the "D" means in steel grade 16MND5.

According to the standard EN 10027:

16 means 0.16 % C
MN 5 means 1.25 % Mn (5 must be divided by 4 to get the Mn mass fraction)

But nothing is specified for D.

Comment: I think it follows the French AFNOR standard, not EN according to p30 here https://publikationen.bibliothek.kit.edu/270046849/3813880 .

Comment: The "Internationaler Stahlvergleich" suggests that D is used in Chinese/Russian steel names.  For example, 16MnDR is equivalent to Material No. 1.0570.  The closest ISO code I could find to 16MnD5 was 16MnCr5 (material no. 1.7131).

Comment: http://www.ccsteels.com/Structural_steel/2305.html is a datasheet from a chinese company. could D mean Mo?

Answer (score 0):

Having looked at the link,

D is for Flat products for cold forming, and is usually followed by two numbers characterising steel

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel_grades#Category_1

Based on the diagram in the same link:
[image]

Comment: You refer to naming according to category 1 (Steel specified by purpose of use and mechanical properties). The steel grade 16MND5 belongs to category 2 (Steel specified by chemical composition). The scheme https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:EN10027-steelgrade-diagram.svg gives more details about the naming specification. According to this scheme, D should be alloy element. But I don't know of any element with element symbol D.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01213899/document) (Table 1, page 4) gives the composition of 16MND5-A508 as

```
> C     S     P     Mn   Si   Ni  Cr   Mo   V Cu Co Al N
> 0.159 0.008 0.005 1.37 0.24 0.7 0.17 0.5  <0.1
> Weight % - iron balance.
```

A508 is the relevant [ASTM](https://www.astm.org/) standards document (not a free publication.)

Comment: It is not ASTM A508 unless is is marked and certified as A508.

Comment: Apparently forging stock likely to be used with ASTM A302, " carbon - 1/2 Mo" . Common pressure vessel steel for use at high temperatures , probably in hydrogen service ( reformers).